# My Vista partition does not boot. How do I fix that?

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning, windows-vista

I accidentally moved my Vista partition, after which it no longer booted. This is a multi-boot laptop, with Windows 7 and Windows XP. Both operating systems don't boot either.

The vexing thing is that I can see the partition with a Linux-based rescue USB - Hiren's BootCD, using GParted - but not with Hiren's BootCD when using MiniXP.

I've used Vista's Recovery ISO but it didn't work.

**My questions:**

1. Is there a Windows-based rescue CD/USB that might see the moved/damaged partition?
2. Is there a way to repair the Vista partition to make it boot again?

Answer (score 1):

Windows install media (DVD/USB) should have recovery tools to re-write the MBR. I imagine you will want the one from your latest OS (Vista)

Comment: Windows install media? that doesn't get shipped any more. ======================================


So what other software is good, when it comes to restoring the MBR?

Comment: I'd [find one](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=download+windows+vista+torrent+iso). or take 30 seconds out of your day to search for [an alternate solution](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/how-to-make-a-windows-vista-repair-disk-if-you-dont-have-one/)